# How to trigger the html scroll when dynamic content is loaded inside the fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a custom fancybox (fancybox2) in which content is loaded dynamically. However has the content grows the box remains fixed in the browser window and the scrollbar for html is not triggered.

However if i run `$.fancybox.update()` it adjusts and shows the scrollbars. How can I automate this without running the above line?

My fancybox definition is as follows

```
$.fancybox({

    href     : '#mycontainer'
    autoSize : true,
    maxWidth :  760,
    fitToView: false,
    padding  : 0,
    fixed    : true,
    autoCenter : true,
    beforeShow :  function(){
       $('.fancybox-overlay-fixed').css({'overflow-y':'auto'});
    },
    afterShow :  function(){
       $('.fancybox-overlay-fixed').css({'overflow-y':'auto'});
    },
 });
```

Comment: What's wrong with using $.fancybox.update() ? Just run it each time you generate dynamic content inside fancybox.

Comment: I have multiple elements within mycontainer which hide/show and I do not want to keep writing the $.fancybox.update function everywhere is there a callback function that detects if the content is off the page ?

Comment: Not that I know of I'm afraid. Your best bet may just be to have overflow-y:scroll; set in this situation - it will also be easier to work with the width of content in the frame in that situation. (I know it could be a little less attractive than it would otherwise be). Personally I wouldn't want to use a lightbox with so much dynamic content... it doesn't sound like it will be all that user-friendly.

Comment: Ok Thank you will continue to use the update function

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs :

`$.fancybox.update()` - Auto-sizes fancyBox `height` to match height of content.

`autoWidth` : If set to true, for 'inline', 'ajax' and 'html' type content height is auto determined. 
Boolean; Default value: `false`

Can you try with ***`autoWidth:true`*** in fancybox config object ?